# Binding a class from var and string?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I output a class from a var and also a string in a blade template?

```
<div :class="data['type'], 'string-class'" v-for="(data, index) in products"></div>
```

Something like the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
<div :class="[data['type'], 'string-class']" v-for="(data, index) in products"></div>
```

if string-class just is a string not a var ,you can use:

```
<div class="string-class" :class="data['type']" v-for="(data, index) in products"></div>
```

Or more combinations.